# Why a cookie login system does not work on an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, iframe, safari

I have two different sites on two different subdomains (using the same domain):

1. Main site: `one.domain.com`
2. Iframe site: `two.domain.com`

The main site (`one.domain.com`) creates an iframe to `two.domain.com`, that second site has a login cookie system which ask for email and password and track the logged in user using a cookie.

The login system works fine if you test it directly on `two.domain.com` but when `two.domain.com` is wrapped in the iframe the login system does not work, after some investigation looks like this problem only occurs on some browser (mainly safari) and the reason is because the browser does not allow to set a cookie in the iframe, how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Safari by default discards cookies set in an iframe unless the host that's serving the iframe has set a cookie before, outside the iframe. Safari is the only browser that does this.

Comment: Even if the host site and the iframe site are using the same domain?

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: @Matt https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/04/safari-third-party-cookies-block/

Answer (score 0):

Safari has a conservative cookie policy that limits the cookie entries to only the pages chosen ("navigated to") by the user. This is probably what is causing the issue. However, this does not apply across subdomains.

Let's say you visit domain.com, then you can set cookies from two.domain.com without direct user interaction (iframe).